# SE Yahoo SSO Authentication fails, how can I access my account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am writing for a friend of mine that is experiencing this issue. He has a few accounts here at SE and logged in through yahoo.com for the account in question.

That email address for some reason is not working anymore, and he cannot access his accounts on the Yahoo side or the SE side.

How can one change one's email address if one cannot access his own accounts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet would be to contact the SE staff, following [the Contact Us link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) you can find at the bottom of each network site. They might have some dedicated identity check procedures in place and might therefore be able to help.